# Performance issues in loading data from Databricks to Azure SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-sql-database, databricks

I am trying to load 1 million records from Delta table in Databricks to Azure SQL database using the recently released [connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver15) by Microsoft supporting Python API and Spark 3.0.

Performance does not really look awesome to me. It takes 19 minutes to load 1 million records. Below is the code which I am using. Do you think I am missing something here?

Configurations:
8 Worker nodes  with 28GB memory and 8 cores.
Azure SQL database is a 4 vcore Gen5 .

```
try:
  df.write \
    .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", "lending_club_acc_loans") \
    .option("user", username) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .option("tableLock", "true") \
    .option("batchsize", "200000") \
    .option("reliabilityLevel", "BEST_EFFORT") \
    .save()
except ValueError as error :
    print("Connector write failed", error)
```

Is there something I can do to boost the performance?

[image]

Comment: Have you identified if this is at the Databricks or the Azure SQL side?   What do you see as Wait Types in SQL when you run this?  You could simply be throttled by the Log Throughput on the SQL side - in which case the resolution is to scale up your SQL DB for the duration of the load then scale down again

Comment: I am not sure Martin where the problem is. I don't think scaling the DB would make any diff as the database is a really powerful one. The I/O on the DB is really low and under control. So am assuming that the problem is on the Databricks end. Something to do with the options here.

Comment: Are you certain about the database?   Have a look at the following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXNRU82x1vs&list=PLlrxD0HtieHjveswk8_gkPD42Te48X4zG&index=2    start from 1:39:00 to get the info on Log Rate Governance which can still occur even if the CPU consumption and Data I/O looks low

Comment: Ok. So did what you said. Kinda helps... The CPU and memory wait times are very low and acceptable. But the Network Io wait time is pretty high.

Comment: I just added the screenshot on the question..

Comment: I check that the Azure SQL DB is using a REDIRECT connection policy and also look at your VNET configuration. Did you do a default Databricks deployment - maybe look at a VNET injection and then maybe consider Private Link for Azure SQL to optimise the VNET connectivity and remove the public endpoint access

Comment: i figured out the issue. Repartitioning the data frame helped in increasing the parallelism of the bulk insert. Earlier it was just single partition on the data frame and I repartitioned it to 8 which resulted in 8 parallel threads of Bulk insert. The load time improved from 12 minutes to 1.7 minutes for 500K records. 2 million records were loaded in 9 minutes as compared to more than 20 minutes earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repartition the data frame. Earlier I had single partition on my source data frame which upon re-partition to 8 helped improve the performance.